# What is the clinical significance of showing the antimicrobial resistance profile of isolates of a certain bacterial species?

Tags: research, bacteria, antibiotics, microbiology

These examples are results from the first three pages of this search in google:

**[site:https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/ "antimicrobial resistance pattern"](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/+%22antimicrobial+resistance+pattern%22&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2018&sxsrf=ALiCzsbVxU9vM9YaN5M7QdN5BaVhPykQIg:1671294790134&ei=Ru-dY87tB4zGlwSSrrugCQ&start=0&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjOqJ-iioH8AhUM44UKHRLXDpQ4FBDy0wN6BAgFEAQ&biw=1455&bih=717&dpr=1.1)**

(Jan 1, 2018 – Today)(I ignored research concerning COVID)

1. [Bacterial uropathogens and burden of antimicrobial resistance pattern in urine specimens referred to Ethiopian Public Health Institute](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34767605/) [2021]
2. [Three Year Study of Infection Profile and Antimicrobial Resistance Pattern from Burn Patients in Southwest Iran](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32547119/) [2020]
3. [Prevalence of uropathogens and their antimicrobial resistance pattern among adult diabetic patients](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34558491/) [2021]
4. [Antibiotic Resistance Pattern Of Acinetobacter Baumannii Isolated From Bacteremia Patients In Pakistan](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/35466635/) [2022]
5. [Blood culture result profile and antimicrobial resistance pattern: a report from neonatal intensive care unit (NICU), Asella teaching and referral hospital, Asella, south East Ethiopia](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30828446/) [2019]

If there is going to be routine clinical susceptibility testing anyway, why does it matter?

Is it mere documentation?

I saw a published research -which I can't remember its title now- that includes detecting antimicrobial resistance profile, and it says in the conclusion: Therefore, antimicrobial susceptibility testing is an essential clinical procedure.

Is it just that?

I don't have time to see every research paper concerned with antimicrobial resistance patterns, to grasp an estimate of where mostly these studies are being conducted, but are these mostly conducted in developing countries where procedures like susceptibility tests might not be done regularly, so that, to show the importance of these tests?

Comment: I am confused by your question. If the paper is about the spread of antimicrobial resistance (which prevents clinicians from using specific antibiotics to treat patients), it is natural for the researchers to report the antimicrobial resistance.

Comment: All i wanted to show from this paper, is what an antimicrobial resistance profile looks like, maybe it's not needed, since it might mislead people.

Comment: I probably should edit my question and provide examples of recent research concerning antibiotic susceptibility patterns.

Comment: If you were a doctor treating patients with bacterial diseases, wouldn't you want some guidance on which antibiotics to use against which bacteria?

Comment: If i am a doctor,i could figure it out my own by the simple use of susectibility testings

Comment: Really? You could do that in time before your patient died? And you could do susceptibility testing in a third world country with no lab and a shortage of antibiotics?

Comment: In addition think about bodies such as governments/medical boards/WHO etc that might want this information to determine trends, provide advice on  what Abs to use, determine cost/patient data etc.